# Core hosted Blazor WASM Swagger for JSON and UI endpoints returning 404

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, swagger-ui

This is my whole code

```
namespace AlprDashboard.Server.Domain
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtension
    {
        
       // OTHER CODES...

        public static void UseSwaggerExtension(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ALPR Dahsboard API", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }
    }
}

'Program.cs'

using AlprDashboard.Server.Domain;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.StaticWebAssets;
using Serilog;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(builder.Environment, builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Host
        .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
        {
            loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom.Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
        });

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCors(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationAuthentication(builder.Configuration);
builder.Services.UseSwaggerExtension();
builder.Services.ConfiguredExtensions();


var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ALPR Dahsboard API");
});

app.UseCors("ApplicationCors");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

When I run it and go to 'https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json' or https://localhost:5001/swagger/index.html', I get a 404.

What am I missing here since I cannot get to the Swagger UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did in my blazor wsam asp.net core hosted project.

install nuget package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore`

[image]

Add configuration in the hosted server project Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();//add this line

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    //add the next 2 lines
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
```

[image]